# SELECT 100 last entries with maximum 3 entries per unique user id

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm having the following request to get all artworks inner join with their user info:

```
SELECT a.*, row_to_json(u.*) as users 
FROM artworks a INNER JOIN users u USING(address) 
WHERE (a.flag != "ILLEGAL" OR a.flag IS NULL) 
ORDER BY a.date DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

How could i have the same query but including no more than 3 entries per user?

Each user have a unique id called "address"

I think DISTINCT ON only work for 1 per user, maybe ROW_NUMBER?

Thank you in advance, i'm pretty new to DB queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra column in which you specify the nth time that the user is in the table. This will look something like this:

```
USER  | N
user1 | 1
user1 | 2
user1 | 3
user2 | 1
user2 | 2
```

Getting the extra column in a new table can be done by using the following code

```
    --Create new Table as T
            WITH T AS (
        SELECT TOP 100 
        a.*, 
        row_to_json(u.*) as users,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u.user ORDER BY a.date DESC) AS N  
        FROM artworks a INNER JOIN users u USING(address) 
        WHERE (a.flag != "ILLEGAL" OR a.flag IS NULL)  )



--Select columns from your new table       
        SELECT columns from T
        WHERE (T.N =1 OR T.N =2 OR T.N =3)
```

Comment: So in my artworks table i needs add an extra column "N"? but what do i put in it? is it an auto increment? How do i link that to each users?

Comment: Ah ok thank you, will try figure when to put the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.user) AS N :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, seem to be working, i just changed PARTITION BY u.user to PARTITION BY u.address and SELECT columns from T by SELECT * from T, as columns was giving me an error but it seem ok. I do some test and let you know, thanks a lot again :)

Comment: Good Luck. Be careful with the Order by a.date desc clause. It will give the most recent user a N=1 and the second most recent user a score of N=2. If you use order by ASC, it will give the least recent user a score of 1. So think about that whether you want to select the most/ least recent users

Comment: Can you mark my answer as solution please? :)

Comment: This code isn't valid Postgres code, so I'm rather confused on why it would be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to your original query will do. Count the resulting records for each user and then filter by the counter value.
I am using `users.address` as the user id.

```sql
SELECT * from 
(
SELECT a.*, row_to_json(u.*) as userinfo,
       row_number() over (partition by u.address order by a.date desc) as ucount
 FROM artworks a INNER JOIN users u ON a.address = u.address 
WHERE a.flag != "ILLEGAL" OR a.flag IS NULL
) t
WHERE ucount <= 3 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

A remark - you have `users` as a column alias and as a table name which may cause confusion. I have changed the alias to `userinfo`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this one give me a 'column "ucount" does not exist', any idea why?

Comment: Because I made a mistake :). Editing now. But actually it has become almost the same as the answer above but w/o CTE.

Comment: Thank you for that, will study both to learn a bit more about this approach